# Adding Property in linq to sql designer doesn't update the class

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table in sql server called customer_Groups. I dragged that table to a linq to sql designer. 
Later I added a field to that table called customers_can_set_delivery as a bit. To reflect this in the linq designer I added a new property to the corresponding data class and set the properties (bit, boolean, name source...)

But when I try to get that field in my code, it doesn't show up with intelisence. Anyone know why that may be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The truth is @Diana Nassar is correct in most cases.

My problem was only fixed after restarting sql server.

Answer (score 1):

When using Linq to SQL and updating any table from the database, you have to re-drag the table again in the .DBML file. That is, delete the current table object in the file and drag it again. Keep the same name for the table of course.

Don't try to add the new fields by hand, it won't get reflected [by design]. Just delete and drag the table again.

I hope this helps.

Comment: In fact, just don't use LinqToSQL. Its pretty defunct now, use EF instead.